# Run a function on child component and call a function on parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the states from a country on change and pass `handleChange` to parent so on Child component i'm rendering the following:

```
<select  className="floating-select"
    id = "country"
    type ="text"
    onChange={handleChange('country')}>
    <option value="" selected>Please select a state</option>
    {
        this.state.countries.map(country => (
        <option value ={country}>{country}</option>
        ))
     }
</select>
```

I'm passing `handleChange` to parent which looks as follows

```
handleChange = input => e =>{
    this.setState({[input]:e.target.value} );
}
```

my question is how can I run a function on the child component that gets data(the states that below to that country ) and still pass handleChange('country') to parent

Comment: You can create a ```onChangeHandler``` inside your child component, which will get the data based on the input and call the ```handleChange``` from the parent and assign it to the ```onChange```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never pass anything up the component tree in react. It's one of the core principles of react. If you want to have access to something in both parent and child then define it in the parent and pass it down to the child. So define the state and the logic (so state.countries and handleChange) in the parent and pass both as props to the child component.

EDIT: Have to respond to your comment here, comments are too small.

You would need to know which country is currently selected, yes, but you save that info in the state as well and update it inside your handler. So your state would look something like

```js
{
   countries: [...listOfAllCoiuntries], 
   country: selectedCountry or undefined, 
   ...otherStateProps
}
```

And inside your handleChange function you set the country prop to whatever the value of the option was so your parent has access to which option was selected through this.state.country. If you pass this.state.country to your child component throught props then you can give that value to the  component via the value prop.

```
<select 
   value={props.selectedCountry} 
   onChange={props.onChange("country")}
   ...otherProps
   >
   {props.countries.map(country => (
        <option value ={country}>{country}</option>
    ))}
</select>
```

Comment: but I would still need to pass the country id to parent to get the new states ?

Comment: Thanks,so i would have to also create a state called "states" on the parent component and send back the new "states" to the child and this is where I'm having trouble

Comment: thank you very much you guided me on the right path!never thought that changing the state on the parent would update the props on the child